# sharing db connection with child_process in nodejs

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm new at node.js and i wonder if there is any way to share a db-connection(lets say db-mysql) with a child_process. Can *child_process.fork()* do that if i communicating with the parent process by send SQL-statements back and get than the results?

Or is this in anyway worse than open a new Connection in the Child?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the advantage over using a separate connection in the child process?

Comment: Thats what i want to know, is there an advantage or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO there is no advantage in sharing a connection over multiple processes. On the one hand, of course, you have fewer open connections, but on the other hand you have the overhead of inter-process communication.

Hence I'd definitely prefer the one-connection-per-process approach.

It's way less work, and way less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing db connections is computationally "expensive". For example if you are running an API server, you will care about the extra latency created by opening and closing your database connection. So I think it depends on your use case.